# ".c" files called by fiona. How to import them?

Tags: python, import, fiona

I downloaded fiona today.  when I try to import it in Python using 'import fiona', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import Collection, supported_drivers, vsi_path
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 7, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: No module named ogrext
```

I checked in my site-packages folder, and ogrext is a "C" file.  I tried commenting out the import to see if it wasn't necessary, but this of course threw another error.

> Specifically, how do I resolve this import error?

More generally, how does one resolve errors involving importing C files into a python library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just install any module by copying all the files to `site-packages`. Some modules are pure Python, but there are many with extensions written in other languages (C, C++, Fortran, etc.) that need to be compiled and linked into libraries before being used, and `fiona` is one of them. This compilation can be done at several stages - by the author, before distributing the module as a wheel, during the `pip install` process, or by downloading the package's source, unzipping/tarring it, and running `python setup.py install`. Unfortunately, Windows doesn't come with a compiler by default, so you either need to install and configure your system for gcc or Visual Studio, or use another method, such as a precompiled installer. Fortunately, `fiona` is available from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows Repository [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona). Download the installer for your version and bit-ness of Python, delete the `fiona` folder in `site-packages`, then run the installer. This site contains a large number of packages for scientific computing, and is my go-to resource when I need to install a new module, especially if it has extensions.

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection, it appears that `fiona` also requires the [`GDAL`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) module, as well as [`six`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six), both of which can be downloaded from Gohlke's repository. I first installed `fiona` only (I already had `six` installed), and got a missing DLL error. I then installed `GDAL`, and `import fiona` worked just fine - I'm not familiar with the module, so I didn't do any further testing, but hopefully everything should work now.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the pre-compiled version with the correct bitness, but it still gives me a "DLL load failed", error.           I suppose I will download from source?

Comment: @Candic3 please see my edit above. It looks like fiona also requires GDAL. Install that and you should be fine.

Comment: The last part worked noted under the heading "EDIT" worked perfectly for me. Installed six with easy_install, then fiona first, then GDAL, both from Gohlke's repository. works. thanks. :)